# How to refer a constant value from one project to another project in java

Tags: java, string, project, constants, final

I have a class where I have few constant values assigned and I want to refer to them in another class which belongs to other project.

Lets say i have a below class :

```
public class sampleConstants {

    private static final String SOME_VALUE = "ABC";
        private static final String SOME_VALUE2 = "DEF";
.
.
.
.

}
```

And the class "sampleConstants" belongs to project "X" and i want to refer to the constant variables from this class in anpother class which belongs to project "Y".

Is it possible ? if yes, Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first get clear on your own requirements: when you change one of those constants, does that mean that you should **immediately** recompile *both* projects?

Or is it OK that you define `SOME_VALUE=1` within X today, and you compile and create a JAR with that constant ... and import that within Y. And when you happen to change `SOME_VALUE=2` tomorrow, your project Y can continue to work with the initial value for some time?

Thus, the *real* point here is: depending on *how* these constants are used, the other solution can be fully okay, but it can also be the wrong approach. You see, when your two projects are tightly coupled, and changing the constant in one place makes it necessary to change it in the second, too ... then the real answer could be to carefully look at the way you defined your projects. Maybe, just maybe, it isn't a good solution to have code that needs these constants to reside in two *different* projects.

Maybe the real solution would be to ensure that all code that uses these constants sits in a single project.

Comment: Thank you! Yes will go with the approach of maintaining a properties file rather than referring it from other project.

Answer (score 1):

you can add project "X" jar into project "Y" and after that you can access constant class.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can add a project with constants as a jar dependency for another your project. Any build tool will allow it to you,

but it's better to consider moving such values in `*.properties` file and keep them separately from java code.

Comment: Hey, Thanks alot! Will go with the properties file.

Comment: But just to be precise: you still have to ask if different projects use the **same** property file then. The last thing to end up with: having issues when *integrating* different projects into a bigger component ... what happens when you then have conflicting values in property files, and such things.

Comment: Yes yes will keep that in mind. I kind of have a requirement where I need to refer to the same property file by multiple projects. And the variable keeps changing and should be reflecting so in all the referred projects.